# Instantiating DbEntityEntry<T> with Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to create a `DbEntityEntry<T>` through reflection for testing purposes. Its constructor is internal, but I would like to call it and pass in an entity:

```
public DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        Type constructedType = typeof(DbEntityEntry<T>);
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        object x = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType, flags, null, new object[] { entity }, null);
```

I get:

> Constructor on type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' not found.

The source for the constructor is:

```
    internal DbEntityEntry(InternalEntityEntry internalEntityEntry)
    {
        DebugCheck.NotNull(internalEntityEntry);

        _internalEntityEntry = internalEntityEntry;
    }
```

Any way to create an instance?

UPDATE:

The original code was actually lifted from one of Marc Gravell's previous answers, but since this post is a candidate for being close, I will provide another try using the Gravell's answer in the suggestion:

```
Type[] argTypes = new Type[] { typeof(T) };
object[] argValues = new object[] { entity };
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof (DbEntityEntry<T>).GetConstructor(flags, null, CallingConventions.Any, argTypes, null);
object obj = ctor.Invoke(argValues);
```

`ctor` is null, so the constructor again could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of asking how to instantiate a 3rd party type with reflection ask how to change your code so that it is testable and does not require hacks. If you look at the `DbEntityEntry` ctor you posted you will see it takes an `InternalEntityEntry` object - another internal class you would have to instantiate (with reflection). So you will end up creating lots of internal objects yourself even if you don't have intimate knowledge of how they are supposed to really work together and if EF happens to create these objects differently your tests might be useless because they still can pass even though the program won't work. Moreover because it is internal stuff it can change in the next version and your test may not work correctly with the new version. There is not enough details in your post to be able to advise a better way. Note that you can create `DbEntityEntry` using public API with the [DbContext.Entry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

Comment: I do believe this is the correct route to approach.

Comment: I'm writing a test for an extension method I have for DbEntityValidationException. In order to test it, I need to create an instance of DbEntityValidationResult, but that needs an instance of DbEntityEntry, and there is where I found this SO question. I agree with you about changing the code but in my scenario, I don't see how I can do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Write an end-to-end test maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.

```
public DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) 
    where T : class
{
    ConstructorInfo constructor = null;

    try
    {
        // Binding flags exclude public constructors.
        constructor = typeof(DbEntityEntry<T>)
            .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, 
            new Type[] { typeof(InternalEntityEntry) }, null);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Finding Constructor", exception);
    }

    if (constructor == null) // || constructor.IsAssembly)
        // Also exclude internal constructors ...  note, were including for this example
        throw new Exception(string.Format("A private or " +
                "protected constructor is missing for '{0}'.", typeof(DbEntityEntry<T>).Name));

    return (DbEntityEntry<T>)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { entity });
}
```

Comment: Looks really good, except `InternalEntityEntry` is `internal` to the EF assembly... Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: Possibly Type.GetType("System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry") but you'd have to double check - i dont think i have the correct EF loaded up tho ... I'll see if i can get EF 5 loaded.

Comment: Thanks Travis, but can we retrieve an internal type this way?

Comment: After further investigation I do believe Pawel is correct in his reasoning ... the InternalEntityEntry itself uses yet another type of InternalContext. You might want to review your method and https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/EntityEntries/InternalEntityEntry.cs before continuing. Also - using the OOB methods he describes is probably going to be better in the long-run.